When initializing Google Play Games, platform_configuration.Valid() suddenly returns false after updating Android Studio
I've used Google Play Games Services (C++ version) for a few years, suddenly when I updated a few SDK's platform_configuration.Valid(); suddenly started to return false.
Note that I have not updated any Google Play Games Services SDK's, nor the Google Play Games Services C++ SDK.
Has anyone experienced the same problem, or does anyone know what is suddenly causing Valid() to return false?
// Init code    
gpg::AndroidInitialization::android_main(app);
auto pc = std::make_unique<gpg::PlatformConfiguration>();
pc->SetActivity(app->activity->clazz);
const auto is_valid = pc->Valid();
// is_valid is suddenly false


I think this is not the place to ask that question. There must be a forum for android studio that is better suited for this question

You might want to reword the question a bit to stave off trivial answers like "The configuration is no longer valid."
